# Send Lead details using email template to specific user email address when lead is created

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template, leads, email-alert, web2lead

I have a simple web-to-lead that works as expected. What I want to do is send a copy of the form details if the lead meets a certain condition. Condition being:

`LeadSource = "example"`.

The email that I want to send a copy of the lead to is a user on the account. I have created an email template that I would like it to use so that certain fields can be omitted in the copy. That looks like so:

```
{!Lead.Id}

NEW LEAD .... 

First Name: {!Lead.FirstName}
Last Name: {!Lead.LastName}
Email: {!Lead.Email}
Phone: {!Lead.Phone}
Company: {!Lead.Company}
Country: {!Lead.Country}
State: {!Lead.State}
City: {!Lead.City}
Lead Source: {!Lead.LeadSource}
Inquiry Details: {!Lead.Inquiry_Details__c}
```

This is how I want the email to be formatted when the new lead is created (from web-to-lead). I don't know much about how to get this to work in salesforce, but I started using an `email alert`. This email alert uses the template created above. The `recipient-type` is specified as the user I want the email copy to go to. Let's say it's `example@example.com`.

Next, I tried to trigger that email alert using a `flow`. The `flow` is structured as so:

[VISUAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWd5I.png)

---

*START*

- Record-Triggered Flow

  - Object: **Lead**
  - Trigger: **A record is created**
  - Conditions: **1**     (condition: `LeadSource = "example"`)
  - Optimize for: **Actions and Related Records**
- EMAIL ALERT

  - alert created (previously mentioned)
  - Record ID: **{!$Record.Id}**

*END*

---

Whenever I run a test and chose a lead to test it on it shows `completed` with no errors. However, I am not getting the email sent to my inbox.

**Summary:**

1. New lead created from web-to-lead with `LeadSource = "example"`
2. Send a copy of that lead via email using a desired email template to a specific email address.
3. Also, maintain the lead in the original `lead` area on SF.

--
I don't have much preference as to how this is accomplished, as long as it works.

Comment: What does `user on the account` mean? are we talking about the `Lead.Owner`?

Comment: @cropredy You know how when you set up the email alert and it says `Recipient Type`? That is set to `user` and the user is listed in the `Available Recipients`. So yes, perhaps that may be the same as the `Lead.Owner`.

Comment: ah - so the emails should go to a fixed user(s). Do you have email deliverability turned on for your sandbox/scratch org?

Comment: @cropredy I am pretty sure. Do you know how to check to make sure?

Comment: `setup | deliverability | All emails`; you can also turn on debug log and you can see if your flow started and executed the email alert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144455/discussion-between-user-and-cropredy).

Comment: `deliverability` is indeed set to `all emails` do you happen to know a solution by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have done so far is correct.

Perhaps, it is the way you are testing it. I imagine you have your `flow` **deactivated** and are running your test with the `debug` feature and are selecting a lead, etc.

However, you are using a `Record-Triggered Flow` with the trigger being `A Record is Created`. When you are running the test and selecting a record, there is no record creation process in effect.

If your test keep returning as `completed`. Try **activating** your `flow` and submit a new lead via your `web-to-lead`. This lead creation should trigger your `flow` and the events within.

Comment: This did it - thank you!